# JavaScript: how to create object from class if I have class name as string?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have some ES2015 classes and need to produce object by one of them in my function.
I get class name as string. How can I do this?
Now I am using `switch … case`, but it look monstrous, you know.

```
let classname = 'MyClass';
new window[classname](); // TypeError: window.MyClass is not a constructor
```

Is it here a more nice way?

Comment: Is there an object which `MyClass` is a property of? If not, you could make one and use that instead of switch/case.

Comment: `classes` (even global ones) are not part of the global object.